# where is the eclipse desktop framework

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm new for java how can i add a button or others like Microsoft visual studio?

Comment: Do you want to change the visual appearance of Eclipse? What for?

Comment: no just write a desktop application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want a GUI builder, you'd better consider NetBeans with its Matisse. I think it is the most popular now for Swing apps.

[This Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Eclipse+GUI+builder) shows a number of GUI builders for Eclipse

Many people prefer building GUI in Swing manually (just writing code) because it is by far not that difficult as in MSVC++ applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Eclipse IDE to help with the development of Java applications, this can be found [on eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Though I'm not sure I understood your question correctly.

Comment: sorry my English i want write a desktop app but a can't found add button or others like a netbeans swing framework

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Eclipse [Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/). However, as pointed out by others, the [GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) from [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/index.html) (formerly known as Matisse) is more popular for Swing development.

Answer (score 0):

Download Netbeans, its visual editor is very good, and will give you a the perfect Swing User Interface. Its also very easy to use.

When making desktop applications, i always do it with Netbeans, if i know the application will be more complicated later, then i do only one or two JFrame classes with Netbeans, and use them in a new project in Eclipse :)